# Como acessar um objeto dentro de um objeto, sendo que sua property name é um número?

Tags: javascript, react

Segue um exemplo do objeto em questão :

```
 obj : {

  "bairro" : "Centro",

  "dAula" : {
    "Quarta" : true,
    "Segunda" : true
  },

  "dVencimento" : "10",

  "dataCadastro" : "10/10/2017",

  "dataInicioContrato" : "27/11/2018",

  "mensalidades" : {

    "2018" : {

      "fev" : true,
      "jan" : true,
      "mar" : true
    }
  },
  "numero" : "111 apto 201",
}
```

Eu recebo uma lista de alunos pelo this.props.lista e incluo eles em uma tabela da seguinte forma:

```
class TabelaMensalidade extends Component {
  render() {
   return(
       <tbody>
        {
         this.props.lista.map((aluno)=>{
          return (
            <tr key={aluno.key}>
            <td>{aluno.bairro}</td>
            <td>{aluno.dVencimento}</td>
            <td>{aluno.dataCadastro}</td>
            <td>{aluno.dataInicioContrato}</td>
            <td>{aluno.dAula.Quarta}</td>
            <td mes='jan' data-value={aluno.mensalidades.2018.jan}>{aluno.mensalidades.2018.jan}
           </tr>
          )
        })
       }
      </tbody>
     )
    }
  }
```

Entretanto não consigo acessar os dados em `aluno.mensalidades.2018.jan`, sendo que em `dAula.Quarta` eu consigo, segue o erro:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jan' of undefined
```

Já tentei usar `aluno.mensalidades[2018].jan` e `aluno.mensalidades['2018'].jan` e o erro permanece o mesmo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo, eu testei o seu código e ele funcionou certinho!
Eu só achei um pouco estranho o modo que você declarou o objeto, mas comigo funcionou tranquilo, eu só usei o código da seguinte forma:

```js
//Declaro uma variável chamada 'obj' como objeto
var obj = {

  "bairro" : "Centro",

  "dAula" : {
    "Quarta" : true,
    "Segunda" : true
  },

  "dVencimento" : "10",

  "dataCadastro" : "10/10/2017",

  "dataInicioContrato" : "27/11/2018",

  "mensalidades" : {

    "2018" : {

      "fev" : true,
      "jan" : true,
      "mar" : true
    }
  },
  "numero" : "111 apto 201",
}


//mando escrever no documento o resultado das mensalidades de jan de 2018
document.write(   obj['mensalidades']['2018']['jan']   );
```

Comment: Acho que o meu problema se encontra na forma como eu estou puxando o objeto do banco. vou editar a pergunta

Comment: Creio que não importa como faça, usar a sintaxe de ponto não irá funcionar. Você precisa selecionar usando `[]` quando o nome da propriedade for um número ou iniciar com qualquer valor que não seja _ $ ou uma letra. Fazer `obj.mensalidades[2018].jan` funciona perfeitamente, qual a sua dificuldade?

Comment: Usando `aluno.mensalidades[2018].jan`, dentro do map retorna o erro, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jan' of undefined` , já tentei colocando aspas também, como por exemplo `aluno.mensalidades['2018'].jan`

Comment: Perdão, a resposta esta correta, o que acontecia era que alguns alunos não tinham esse valor no banco ( por não terem pago) eu acabei não filtrando eles e o erro era gerado por não entrar o valor dentro do objeto